# how to change default parameter values at pipeline level dynamically in azure data factory while moving from dev to prod

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have few parameters specified at pipeline level in ADF and i have used default values in dev environment.Now i want to move this pipeline to prod environment and want to change the parameter values according to the production.

Earlier is SSIS we used to have configurations(sql,xml...) to do such changes without changing anything in the SSIS package.

can we do the same thing in ADF i:e without changing the default values manually in the package,can we use values stored in sql table to pass as pipeline parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the values defined in a pipeline parameter as long as you are going to have a trigger on it. Just make sure to publish different versions of triggers in dev and prod repositories and pass different values to the pipeline parameters.

If however you want to change parameters, you can do so by invoking the pipeline from a parent pipeline through an execute pipeline activity. The values you pass as parameters to the execute pipeline activity can be coming from a lookup (over some configuration file or table).

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. In case of first option I still feel it is manual way of changing and publishing.The second option seems to work because we can do sql configuration type but for this we have to create one more pipeline just to pass values.

Comment: Do you use Azure Devops/GIT with ADF?

Comment: We are planning to use azure devops. Can you please let me know how devops can handle this?

Comment: You can look into the concept/usage of parameters of Azure Devops.