# Azure Data Factory: Debug Data Flow with lots of parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm looking for some best practices when debugging a dataflow with lots of parameters.
Currently, we fill in the values manually and this can take a long time in some cases. Am therefore looking for a more efficient way. Does anyone have experience with this?

Kind regards,

Thnks in advance

Dickkieee

Comment: Can you use the default value option in the parameters?

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your reply. Since we're using dynamic expressions, I don't think that works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to supply values to our data flow parameters to perform data preview. Any of the below approaches you can opt as per your convenience.

1. Manually supply values to your parameters whenever data flow preview option you try
2. **You can have default values for your parameters, so that whenever you try to data preview you do not need to manually enter the values for all parameters.**

Thank you

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT, is there also a solution to override the default values of the parameters when deploying to test or prod? I'm aware of the global params, but unfortunately they can be used for this purpose

Comment: Hi, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319385/how-to-change-default-parameter-values-at-pipeline-level-dynamically-in-azure-da and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT, I guess this solution is suitable for pipelines. In our case we want to use default params in, for example a dataset. Is there another we we could do this? Thanks again!

Comment: It's a parquet file where we have a parameter called runId.

Comment: Please create a new thread instead adding queries in the comment section.